# Apple Music streaming subscription - add own CDs?

Tags: music, apple-music, streaming

I have one question concerning the Apple Music subscription. I have a largish collection of ripped CDs which I would like to add to my `Album` section in Music. Is there a tool which can help me with this, i.e. I don't feel like manually searching for hundreds of Albums - is there a batch tool which I can use to add these local albums? I only want them as streaming and not as the music matching service from apple (if it still exists).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. If I add the albums on y Mac running Catalena to the Music library, they will be synced to the other devices for streaming.